# Game Center - Show a set of leaderboards

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I just asked this question for Google Play Services, but I also have a Game Center implementation for iOS. My game has two modes - normal and hard. At the end of a game I would like to be able to show the leaderboards for the current mode instead of showing all the leaderboards - that would be a confusing mess. Is this possible with Game Center?

Comment: Instead of me answering its best you look at the docs or an apple example because they go through it A-B I was just going to give you B since you didn't provide any code. Anyhow this is a great starting point https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW44

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @soulshined, you'll want to first check out the docs in the Game Center Programming Guide, specifically the section on [Displaying the Standard Leaderboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH6-SW26). It'll explain this much better than short answers here will.

Basically though, you'll first create an instance of a `GKGameCenterViewController`, tell it that you want to display a leaderboard, then specify which leaderboard to display, and finally present the new view controller to the user. Like so (based on some tweaked sample code from Apple):

```
- (void) showLeaderboard: (NSString*) leaderboardID
{
    GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];
    if (gameCenterController != nil)
    {
       gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
       gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateLeaderboards;
       gameCenterController.leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardID;
       [self presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```